# List all intervals made by inherited array of intervals

Tags: algorithms

i have a grading system which works like this:

You have a array of intervals with grades:

```
[9, Inf) => A; [7, 9) => B; ... (-Inf, 1) => F
```

But you can create also inherited grading system by new array:

```
[10, Inf) => A+; [7, 8) => B-; ...
```

Now when I need to get the grade I go from bottom to top and always check whether the number fits in any interval in that level, if not I go one level up.

Now I need a list of all intervals without overlapping.

So in this case it would looks like this:

```
[10, Inf) => A+; [9, 10) => A; [8, 9) => B; [7,8) => B-; ... (-Inf, 1) => F
```

Currently I have no idea how to do so. I appreciate any support or help, thank you. :)

PS: The boundary numbers are float. And intervals can be (x,y), [x,y), (x,y] or [x,y]

Comment: Ok, sounds like a fairly simple job, without "big data" requirements.  So, you create a data structure to represent the notion of an interval.  Then use an array or list of those.  Then iterate comparing one interval to another, and any two overlapping ones should be trimmed so they don't overlap.  Finally, iterate until no changes.  Handle a few special cases like one interval is contained entirely within another (this could mean error or you don't have enough information to proceed, e.g. in splitting the larger interval).

Comment: Note that in the very case you presented, you don't need to merge. You can simply check if your value is found in the second series first, and use the first one when not. That's equivalent to the merging you've done. I'm lacking scope info to help further. If all cases are this simple, it's pretty straightforward, but... Can you inherit multiple parents? Is it possible to have ranges which overlap such that one range is inside another, and doesn't share any boundary (e.g. [1, 4] [2, 3])? Is there any priority to be given to the parent vs child when inheriting?...

Comment: @Joanis Well the task is to show the teacher a list of grading intervals in some understandable way. You can inherit from only one parent. Overlaping intervals can't be in one entity (parent or child), but can be found when inheriting from parent to child (e.g. Parent: [1, 4] Child: [2, 3] and vice versa) child have always greater priority than parent.